# How can i return stock bought and sold for each company individually/separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this problem, we are given this dictionary whose keys are names; which has tuples with 3 values: in the 3-tuple, a stock name, number of shares traded for that transaction (int), and price of each share (int).

```
new_dict = {
    'Carl': [('Intel', 30, 40), ('Dell' , 20, 50), ('Intel',-10, 60), 
('Apple', 20, 55)],
    'Barb': [('Intel', 20, 40), ('Intel',-10, 45), ('IBM',   40, 30), 
('Intel',-10, 35)],
    'Alan': [('Intel', 20, 10), ('Dell',  10, 50), ('Apple', 80, 80), ('Dell', 

-10, 55)],
    'Dawn': [('Apple', 40, 80), ('Apple' ,40, 85), ('Apple',-40, 90)]
  }
```

I am creating a traded function that takes in new_dict and returns a dictionary where keys are all the stocks that appear in transactions; the value is a stock is a 2-list where the first index is the number of shares of that stock bought and whose second index is the number of shares of that stock sold. **Bought** is positive stock and **sold** is any stock with a negative number.

The output of this function should be:

```
{'Intel': [70, 30], 'Dell': [30, 10], 'Apple': [180, 40], 'IBM': [40, 0]}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def traded(database :{str: (str, int, int)}) ->dict:
    result_dict = dict()
    intel = []
    dell = []
    apple = []
    ibm = []



    for key, val in database.items():
        pos_sum = 0
        for x in val:
            if x[1] > 0:
               pos_sum += x[1]

    return pos_sum
```

I am trying to do this for each stock company individually by having separate lists for each stock company, but I feel that is just tedious. I'm not sure what other techniques there are to do this for each stock company individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following implementation which uses [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to store result and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to iterate over values in the dict. The defaultdict allows us to create initial values for keys that do not yet exist, in this case the initial value is a 2-element list containing 0s.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

def traded(database):
    dd = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
    for stock_name, quantity, _ in chain.from_iterable(database.values()):
        dd[stock_name][quantity < 0] += abs(quantity)
    return dict(dd)

print(traded(new_dict))
```

Prints:

```
{'Apple': [180, 40], 'Dell': [30, 10], 'IBM': [40, 0], 'Intel': [70, 30]}
```